# Finding mixed Nash equilibrium

Tags: calculus, self-learning, game-theory, economics, nash-equilibrium

I have following simultaneous move game table

[Game table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2909.jpg)

Player 1 can take one of three actions A,B,C and player 2’s possible actions are D,E,F.

First of all I found pure Nash equilibrium

And (B,E) and (C,D) are pure Nash equilibrium.

Secondly I want to find mixed Nash equilibrium

For that I calculate it

$$u(A,p_2)=1p_d+4p_e+2(1-p_d-p_e)=2p_e-p_d+2$$
$$u(B,p_2)=2p_d+5p_e+3(1-p_d-p_e)=2p_e-p_d+3$$
$$u(c,p_2)=3p_d+2p_e-6(1-p_d-p_e)=-4p_e-3p_d+6$$

And I know that $$u(A,p_2)=u(B,p_2)=u(C,p_2)$$

But after this calculation, I cannot reach any result.

I’m stuck at this point.

Please help me to find mixed Nash equilibrium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that in any mixed strategy Nash equilibrium players assign a positive probability only to strategies that aren't dominated. Note that strategy $B$ dominates $A$ and because of this last fact, it can be shown that there is a mixed strategy with $D$ and $E$ that dominates $F$.

The mixed strategy Nash equilibrium can be found from the equations:

$3p+4(1-p)=4p+(1-p)$

$2q+5(1-q)=3q+2(1-q)$

Where $p$ is used for the probability distribution over the first player.

Comment: How did you write These equations? I don’t understand it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try calculating the mixed strategy equlibrium as if player 1 only had strategies $B$ and $C$ and the second player only had $D$ and $E$.

Comment: Okay I see now. Thanks a lot. Well this is my last question. I guess there is no more equilibrium except for those we found. How can I show there is no more other equilibrium?

Comment: Well, yet again any Nash equilibrium has to belong to the set of undominated strategies. You already found the equlibrium in pure strategies, and since the undominated strategies form a 2 by 2 matrix there can only be one mixed strategy nash equlibrium.

Comment: Dear Daniel Ordoñez thank you for your great explanation. Please also look at my another question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2774659/subgame-nash-equlibrium

Comment: Can I ask something? You said that “B dominates A”. Yes I see this. And thus, you use only B and C for player 1. Similarly, D and E dominat. So you use the mixed strategy with D and E for player 2. But also can we say that there is a mixed strategy with D and F that dominates E? If yes, in this case we use D and F for player 2. Right? Dear Daniel. Sorry I ask too much but just I try to learn. Thanks.

Comment: By the way thanks a lot for your great solution!