# Subgame Nash Equlibrium

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, abstract-algebra, self-learning, game-theory

I have the following static game with complete information.

[image]

First of all the players play the static game depicted above infinitely repeated. They discount payoffs with the common discount factor $\delta$. And I am interesting in supporting (T,R),(T,R),...) as subgame perfect equilibrium I want to calculate the minimal discount factor needed so that my strategy supports this outcome. And secondly, this static game is assumed to be finite.y related. Now, I am I tested in supporting ((T,L),(D,R),...,(T,L), (D,R)) as a subgame perfect equilibrium. Again I want to implement this outcome as a subgame perfect equilibrium. And I would like to calculate again the minimum discount factor neeeded so that my strategy supports this outcome.

————

For the infinitely repeated case, I guess I should use trigger stategies. I found some examples related to such type questions on the google. But I cannot understand its solutions. And thus, I cannot apply these solutions in my examples. So I cannot write anything about my trails. Sorry for that. Please show me how can I solve thesetypes of questions.

Note that this question is the continue of that question [Finding bet response function to the opponent mixed Nash strategy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2774577/finding-bet-response-function-to-the-opponent-mixed-nash-strategy) . I really try to solve these parts but I cannot. I stuck at this point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the grim trigger strategy for the infinitely repeated games. This method employs the use of a credible threat that would force the player to stick to the outcome agreed upon (given a certain value of delta) and not deviate. Since you cannot deviate, this implies, it holds as a nash equilibrium.

Now, to hold (T,R) as a Nash, both players will say this to each other:
We shall play (T,R) till one person defects then play (T,L) or (D,R) forever(depending on who is defecting; if player 1 defects then they play (T,L) forever).

We then compare the payoffs from sticking to this strategy with the payoff that one yields from defecting.

So, from sticking to (T,R), a player gets:

$4+ 4\delta + 4\delta^2 +........$=$\frac{4}{1-\delta}$

By deviating, one gets:

$5 + 1\delta + \delta^2+......=5+ \frac{\delta}{1-\delta}$

We want to support (T,R) as a nash equilibrium and therefore we want:

$\frac{4}{1-\delta} \geq 5+ \frac{\delta}{1-\delta}$

Solving this yields that $\delta \geq 1/4$

Then, given that $\delta$ satisfies the above condition, (T,R) can be supported as a Nash Equilibrium.

EDIT: Finitely repeated case, for periods T=2.

Just realised it right now, you can't hold onto (T,R) as an equilibrium in the finitely repeated games because you can't incentivise the other person to play (T,R) as what will you play in the next stage for that person to benefit from sticking to the outcome?

Comment: I guess this is the solution for the repeated infinitely case. Right?

Comment: Well, how can I find these for the repeated finitely case? Also please explain the second part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The solution is just for the infinitely repeated case using the grim trigger strategy (the one most commonly used). The minimal delta is 1/4 in this case where the payoff from deviation and the payoff from cooperation is the same. Then, you can hold (T, R) as a nash equilibrium. Also, look into the prisoner's dilemma for both, the finite and infinitely repeated case, it's interesting!

Comment: Okay I see thanks again. Also please add the solution for finitely repeated case? 

Comment: For finitely repeated case, you'll have to consider cases where the periods equal to 2, 3 and so on. I'd suggest sticking with periods up till 2 now. An important result that is quite helpful is that " In finitely repeated games, in the last stage, players can ONLY play the nash equilibria"

Comment: I'll edit my answer to account for the finite case where number of periods =2.

Comment: Okay if you edit your answer for finitely repeated case, I really will be happy

Comment: Please check it now. You can't hold onto (T,R) as a nash equilibrium in finitely repeated games. As in the last stage, you MUST play the nash equilibrium, which implies, that one person will benefit and other will lose out (due to the nature of the payoffs) and thus, you can't incentivise holding (T,R) as an equilibrium here. The players will have an incentive to deviate.

Comment: The the will deviate either (T,L) or (D,R). In the next stage, the person may use either of them. right?

Comment: Yes, they can use either of (T,L) or (D,R) in the last stage as both are Nash Equilibria.

Comment: Okay great! Well, how can I find delta in this case? Dear Asad

Comment: There is no question of finding delta in this case as no such delta exists to maintain (T,R) as a nash equilibrium.